# Performance of iterator function next() vs. advance() in for-loops

Tags: c++, list, opencv, iterator

is there any difference in performance between `next()` and `advance()`? I am asking as my code is very slow and I try to figure out why.

I go through several lists of different types and use a for loop where I update three different iterators. The code looks something like this:

```
listPt3d l1;        // std::list<cv::Point3d>
listlistPt2i l2;    // std::list<std::list<cv::Point2i>>
listlistPt3d l3;    // std::list<std::list<cv::Point3d>>

listPt3d::iterator iter1, iter1_2;
listlistPt2i::iterator iter2, iter2_2;
listlistPt3d::iterator iter3, iter3_2;

// compare lists with each other
for (iter1 = l1.begin(), iter2 = l2.begin(), iter3 = l3.begin();
     iter1 != prev(l1.end());
     iter1 = next(iter1), iter2 = next(iter2), iter3 = next(iter3))
{
    for (iter1_2 = next(iter1), iter2_2 = next(iter2), iter3_2 = next(iter3);
         iter1!= l1.end();
         iter1_2 = next(iter1_2), iter2_2 = next(iter2_2), iter3_2 = next(iter3_2))
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

My questions is whether it is faster to use `iterator = next(iterator)`or `advance(iterator, 1)` or whether this is both the same. I could imagine that advance is a bit faster as there is no assignment operator.

I avoided to use the `++` operator as I have the lists of lists and therefor get problems with `++`.

If there is any other possibility to iterate through the for loops then please tell me as I'm not that familiar with such things. Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess, that thete is no real difference (you'd have to measure). What you probably should do however is to replace your lists with vectors.

Comment: I don't see why `++` is problematic for you.

Comment: Probably more important is the question of what `//Whatever` is

Comment: I use the functions `splice()` and `erase()` a lot. I'm actually restructuring the structures completely. That is why I am using lists instead of vectors.

Comment: @Lingxi
I just tried the `++` again and it seems to work. Don't know what was wrong then... The complexity is also of O(1) then, right?

Comment: @jkl I think the issue here is not about the asymptotic time complexity but about the implicit time constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the standard (N3337 in this case), calling `std::next` effectively calls `std::advance` internally (this isn't required, but it behaves as such). As such, `std::advance` is more efficient in theory, but there's not likely to be an appreciable performance difference in practice.
It's worth noting, however, that `std::advance` can not be called with an r-value iterator as its first argument (like what you'd get from calling `begin()` or `end()`.

Regarding your complaint about your code running slowly. That's unlikely to be caused by how you're incrementing your iterators, unless you're doing very little in the body of the nested loop.
Since you stated that you're calling `erase` and `splice` in there somewhere, I am tempted to guess that one or both of those is part of the problem.
That being said, I would recommend you profile your code before attempting further optimisations. That way you are making informed decisions about what you're optimising.

Comment: I already tried to avoid `splice()` by using `push_back()` instead and write the iterators into another list in that way, e.g.: `list.push_back(iteratorToBeSpliced)`. That doesn't make any difference though. But I will go on searching for the problem. What exactly do you mean with "profiling the code"? I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I tried out `++` operator, `next()` and `advance()` and `advance()` is actually faster. As the rest is so slow one can really see a difference in the time performance. So I will keep it like this now and go on optimising. Thanks.

Comment: "Profiling your code" means to use a cpu profiling program (such as gprof on linux or the Visual Studio Profiler on Windows) to measure how long the CPU spends executing the various parts of your code.

Comment: Cool. I'll have a look at that to find out where my problems are. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a look at their mentioned complexities,both look the same.

std::advance
Complexity
Linear.
However, if InputIt additionally meets the requirements of RandomAccessIterator, complexity is constant.

std::next
Complexity
Constant for random-access iterators.
Otherwise, linear in n.

From an implementation perspective, especially for advance in lists case, maybe it could be bettered with skiplists..but i guess it would have been mentioned if that were the case.

Comment: `std::next` should always be constant, as it is equivalent to advancing by one position.

Comment: I sometimes got the error message that the list iterator is not dereferencable during my calculations. That is why I changed it. I thought it is working, because the sublists are of different lengths.